# opencart: How to add static html home page and change logo and navbar link to it

Tags: php, html, opencart

I am new to using Opencart and Php open source frameworks in general, and have been searching the forums and haven't found anything to create a non-default home page that is simply static html with no database it needs.

I was wondering how to do this in the source code, if it is possible.
So far I have created an index.html file and that shows up as the home page. But when I click the logo for the site, it goes back to the index.php file, to be exact: yourstoreurl/index.php?route=common/home

Secondarily, I will likely want more than one static page, not just home, and would like them to show up in the navbar where the tabs for your products are displayed. For instance, in the default site, have navbar links for "home" which I want to be static html, and "about" which I want to be static html, before "Desktops" and "Laptops and Notebooks" https://demo.opencart.com/

How could this be done?
The reason I want to do this is to have some written content at the entrance of the site, and have html & css experience so would like to create it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, bro open cart is a database-backed app. 
Use a custom static web page as your home page, put your shop in a subdirectory, and put a link on the home page to the shop.

Comment: There are tools that you just "add on" to static HTML pages to add shopping cart functionality.  OpenCart is not one of them; it's a complete website.

Comment: I was able to do what you suggested. For future reference, what tools would you recommend to as you say "add on" to static HTML pages to add shopping cart functionality? One that I looked into a bit is [Flatmarket](https://github.com/christophercliff/flatmarket).